# Get string between single or double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I am getting the string data in between single or double quotes in the following code. Is it possible to combine this into a single command or simplify ?

Examples:

```
 STR_NAME = '12345'
 STR_NAME = "12345"
```

Code:

```
$match = "STR_NAME = '12345'";
if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $match, $m)) {
    $val = $m[1]; //found string in double quotes
  } else {
    if (preg_match("/'([^']+)'/", $match, $m)) {
      $val = $m[1]; //found string in single quotes
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
 echo $val;
 12345
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Does this help: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: @SalmanA:  Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backreference `\1` to the first quote found:

```
preg_match('/(["\'])([^\1]+)\1/', $match, $m);
echo $m[2];
```

- `(["\'])` Match and capture in group 1 `"` or `'`
- `([^\1]+)` Match and capture in group 2 one or more not `^` what was captured in group 1

  - You can use many things here that don't match the following quote like `(.+?)`
- `\1` Match what was captured in group 1 `"` or `'`

Would not match something like `STR_NAME = "1234'`.

If the data is consistent and predictable then you might be able to get away with:

```
["\']([^"\']+)["\']
```

Or:

```
["\'](.+?)["\']
```

Comment: I think the first pattern would still match unwanted values https://3v4l.org/3pRsG due to `[^\1]+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird:  Without more info we don't know if they're unwanted or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a a capturing group with a character class `(["'])` to match either `'` or `"` and a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to group 1.

To match what is in between you can use `.+?` to match at least 1 character.

The value is in capture group 2

```
(["'])(.+?)\1
```

- `(["'])` Capture group 1 (For the backreference)
- `(.+?)` Match 1+ times any char except a newline
- `\1` Backreference to group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KN5djz/1)

Note that you don't have to escape the `'` in the character class.